# How to view this svg file on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I created [an svg file](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8NKGkZpniOMbjFQVzlXeVVCbDQ) from a photo using http://www.autotracer.org, but can't view the image in any of my browsers (Chrome/FF/Safari).

Chrome and FF display the underlying code in the browser rather than the image; Safari shows nothing, just a white page.

**Edit:** Perhaps this should/could be migrated to the apple stackexchange?

Comment: Have you put the image on a web server? If not does the file name end with .svg. If it is on a web server then you're serving it with the wrong mime type.

Comment: In 2017, all major browsers can display SVG file properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standalone SVG files are required to have the `xmlns` attribute specified.

If you change the second line of your file to:

```
<svg width="3032" height="2008" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

The SVG will work properly when loaded into a browser.